# Todo app for recurring tasks updates the next due dates based on the 'done' date

Tags: linux, offline, reminders, todo

I have a few recurring tasks like watering our plants in every week. If I forget to water them on Monday and do it on Friday I should not water them again on the next Monday, it should be on the next Fridays (+7, +14, +21 days) and remains me on Fridays (until I forget it again to water them).

The same is true, for example, for charging unused batteries in every six months. If I forget to do it and I do it in March instead of January it is unnecessary to charge them again in July (January + 6 months), I'm good with September (March + 6 months), then the next March, next September etc.

So missing a due date usually is not a big problem, keeping the interval between the actions is more important. I would like a reminder software which automatically modifies the next due date based on the last 'done' date.

Must:

- remember completion dates of tasks
- have an "I have done it a minute ago" function which schedules the next action according to the completion date
- run offline, store data offline
- support Linux (Debian/Ubuntu)

Optional:

- email notification

Comment: If you can't remember to water the plants, do you think that you will remember to udpate the program?  ;-)

Comment: Seriously, since you have to open the reminder program anyway, you _could_ just manually change the next due date.

Comment: @Mawg: I forgot to mention a popup or some automatic reminder feature.

Comment: What is also missing is that your use cases require a period counting back from the next due date in which taking the action results in skipping the next due date. E.g. 4 days: if your weekly watering is 2 days late (5 early for the next) do not skip, but if 4 days late (3 early for the next = within that 4 day period): skip.

Comment: @JanDoggen: I did my best and edited the question. Could you check it, please? Let me know if you find any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

**Getting Things GNOME!** ([GTG](http://gtgnome.net/)) is a personal tasks and TODO-list items organizer for the [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) desktop environment inspired by the [Getting Things Done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) (GTD) methodology.
Recurring tasks can be [set](https://sagarghuge.files.wordpress.com/2014/07/screenshot-from-2014-07-04-202139.png) and there is "Send task via email" plugin for GTG.

Comment: I've tried version `0.3.1-1` (available in Linux Mint 17) but it does not have this feature. I've also tried the current PPA version for Trusty (`0.3.1.r88~ubuntu14.04.1`) on the same Linux Mint instance but unfortunately I could not even start it.